# Given an infinite Cartesian grid and you need to find minimal number of lattice points

Tags: combinatorics

You are given an infinite Cartesian grid and you need to find minimal number of lattice points such that if no matter how we will choose that much lattice points there will always exists two points that if we connect them with straight line then the middle point of that line will also be lattice point. Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: What is the space you are working in ? $\mathbb Z^n$ ? $\mathbb R^n$ ?

Comment: Besides, Welcome to Math SE. You have typed in your exercise, but nothing showing your attempts to solve this homework ; please do it...

Comment: I suspect it is $\Bbb Z^n$, or possibly just $\Bbb Z^2$. If so, it's quite a straightforward problem. @JeanMarie

Comment: Space is not given
And honestly saying, I don't completely understand the question and I can't solve it

Comment: As it is asked, it is not understandable. I am afraid nobody will answer you. Is it the original text or have you translated it from another language ?

Comment: This is the original one.

Answer (score 1):

The minimal number is $5$. (Four points are not enough because $\{(0,0), (0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$ is a counterexample.)

Given any five lattice points $\{(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), (x_3,y_3), (x_4,y_4), (x_5,y_5)\}$, one of two things must hold, by the pigeonhole principle:

- either there are $1\le a<b<c\le 5$ such that $x_a, x_b, x_c$ are all odd,
- or there are $1 \le a < b<c \le 5$ such that $x_a, x_b, x_c$ are all even.

The reason we do this is that in either case, $\frac{x_a + x_b}{2}$ and $\frac{x_a + x_c}{2}$ and $\frac{x_b + x_c}{2}$ are all integers: the sum of two odd numbers is divisible by $2$, and the sum of two even numbers is divisible by $2$.

Next we look at $y_a, y_b, y_c$. By the pigeonhole principle again, either two of them will be odd or else two of them will be even.

Say that $y_a$ and $y_c$ are both odd. (The other cases for $y_a, y_b, y_c$ are identical.) Now the midpoint of $(x_a,y_a)$ and $(x_c,y_c)$ is a lattice point, because the coordinates of $(\frac{x_a+x_c}{2}, \frac{y_a+y_c}{2})$ are both integers.